# BeyondCompare partial file name comparison

Tags: beyondcompare

I am using BeyondCompare software and would like to know how to compare partial filenames on 2 different folders.

Ex:

**Source Directory:**
TestFile1_DEV.txt
TestFile2_DEV.txt

**Target Directory:**
TestFile1_QA.txt
TestFile2_QA.txt

When I am comparing folders, I want to align the files like this:

TestFile1_DEV.txt <--> TestFile1_QA.txt

TestFile2_DEV.txt <--> TestFile2_QA.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Session` -> `Session Settings` (select the tab Misc) and set the Alignment Override like this:

[image]

The result is in the background of the screenshot.

Comment: @stoniel2: Can you accept the answer or give some more details, why the solution does not work?